# Why does VirtualAlloc fail for 2GB even when running as 64bit process?

Tags: winapi, memory-management, virtual-memory

This runs fine

```
    int GB = 2;
    int bytes = GB * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

    LPVOID memory = VirtualAlloc(
        0,
        bytes-1, // 2GB - 1
        MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE);
```

while here, as soon as I reach 2GB, it fails

```
    int GB = 2;
    int bytes = GB * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

    LPVOID memory = VirtualAlloc(
        0,
        bytes, // 2GB
        MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE);
```

with Windows error message "The parameter is incorrect". Why is this the case? Actually I would like to allocate even much more virtual memory.

Comment: I rolled back the edit, since it changed the question, and invalidated the answer (`int` and `long` are different types, even though the rationale is the same on an LLP64 implementation).

Comment: right, maybe better understandable that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `int` is a 32-bit signed quantity on the Windows platform. The value *2GB - 1* is the largest representable positive value, whereas *2GB* has the topmost bit set, and is interpreted as a negative value.

The binary representation of the values is:

```
 3         2         1         0
10987654321098765432109876543210

01111111111111111111111111111111  2GB - 1
10000000000000000000000000000000  2GB
```

When the value *2GB* is passed to `VirtualAlloc`, it is sign-extended and converted to a `SIZE_T`. The resulting value is `1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000` in binary representation (dec: `18446744071562067968`, hex: `0xffffffff80000000`). In other words: huge.

If you need to allocate 2GB or more, use a `SIZE_T` instead of an `int`. It is declared in *basetsd.h* as follows:

```
typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T, *PSIZE_T;
```

It is large enough to identify counts or ranges that span the entire range of a pointer.

Comment: uh, stupid me, sorry, you are certainly totally correct. The thing is, changing to long causes the very same result. At the moment it looks, like the process is not really running under 64bit.

Comment: @citykid: A `long` is 32 bits as well, when using the Microsoft Compiler. You would have to go with `unsigned long long` instead, if you can use C++11 features. Or simply use `SIZE_T`.

Comment: @IInspectable Pedantry mode on. `long` is 32 bits for any sane compiler targeting Windows. It's the platform that determines that rather than the compiler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You are right, it is the target platform that controls the size of data types (Reference: [Abstract Data Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384083.aspx)). And for anyone interested: [Why did the Win64 team choose the LLP64 model?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/31/363790.aspx)